# Transfer cookies with Spring rest template

Tags: java, spring, cookies, resttemplate

I have two services for a spring boot, I need to transfer cookies. The only option I have is to push cookies through the controller further and, when calling the second service, add them through **HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Cookie", cookieHeader );**

to RestTemplate. Is there a more elegant solution for this ?

Comment: What isn't elegant about this? Yo need a new request so you need to copy the cookies/headers from the incoming request, to the new request you are making.